# Error occurred reading HTTP response: Connection reset in Micronaut

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-client

I have a Micronaut application which calls other microservice using Micronaut declarative HTTP client. Sometimes we are getting error response which says **Error occurred reading HTTP response: Connection reset**.

Below is the detail error. Can someone help me to understand the issue and available fix.

"errorMessage":"Error occurred reading HTTP response: Connection reset","stack_trace":[{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"exceptionCaught","fileName":"DefaultHttpClient.java","lineNumber":2306,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient$11"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"invokeExceptionCaught","fileName":"AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java","lineNumber":302,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"invokeExceptionCaught","fileName":"AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java","lineNumber":281,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"fireExceptionCaught","fileName":"AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java","lineNumber":273,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"fireExceptionCaught","fileName":"CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java","lineNumber":424,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"exceptionCaught","fileName":"ChannelHandlerAdapter.java","lineNumber":92,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerAdapter"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"fireExceptionCaught","fileName":"CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java","lineNumber":145,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$1"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"exceptionCaught","fileName":"ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java","lineNumber":143,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"exceptionCaught","fileName":"CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java","lineNumber":231,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"invokeExceptionCaught","fileName":"AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java","lineNumber":302,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"invokeExceptionCaught","fileName":"AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java","lineNumber":281,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"fireExceptionCaught","fileName":"AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java","lineNumber":273,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"exceptionCaught","fileName":"SslHandler.java","lineNumber":1105,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"invokeExceptionCaught","fileName":"AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java","lineNumber":302,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"invokeExceptionCaught","fileName":"AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java","lineNumber":281,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"fireExceptionCaught","fileName":"AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java","lineNumber":273,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"exceptionCaught","fileName":"DefaultChannelPipeline.java","lineNumber":1377,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"invokeExceptionCaught","fileName":"AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java","lineNumber":302,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"invokeExceptionCaught","fileName":"AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java","lineNumber":281,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"fireExceptionCaught","fileName":"DefaultChannelPipeline.java","lineNumber":907,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"handleReadException","fileName":"AbstractNioByteChannel.java","lineNumber":125,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"read","fileName":"AbstractNioByteChannel.java","lineNumber":177,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"processSelectedKey","fileName":"NioEventLoop.java","lineNumber":719,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"processSelectedKeysOptimized","fileName":"NioEventLoop.java","lineNumber":655,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"processSelectedKeys","fileName":"NioEventLoop.java","lineNumber":581,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"run","fileName":"NioEventLoop.java","lineNumber":493,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"run","fileName":"SingleThreadEventExecutor.java","lineNumber":986,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"run","fileName":"ThreadExecutorMap.java","lineNumber":74,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2"},{"classLoaderName":"app","moduleName":null,"moduleVersion":null,"methodName":"run","fileName":"FastThreadLocalRunnable.java","lineNumber":30,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable"},{"classLoaderName":null,"moduleName":"java.base","moduleVersion":"14-ea","methodName":"run","fileName":"Thread.java","lineNumber":832,"nativeMethod":false,"className":"java.lang.Thread"}

I tried with adding couple of client configuration but still getting the issue.